# How to attach ids to a sequence in F#?

Tags: f#, sequence, counter

I have a `seq<'A>`. I want to map this to a `seq<(int, 'A)>`, where the integer is an auto-generated sequence of values starting at 0. I know I can do this with a mutable counter and a loop, but is there a more elegant way to do this, perhaps using `Seq.map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `Seq.mapi`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340431.aspx

```
let a = [ 1; 2; 3 ]
let s = a |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i,x)
```